# How can i assign multiple commands in single buttons in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Suppose there two functions name
Func1 and func2 and there one button name OK,
How can I execute func1 or func2 if user Entry is 1 and press “OK” then func1 will executed, and if Entry is two then fun2 will executed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this example out, where ive used `messagebox` to show some action, you can replace it with whatever you have to do inside the function.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox

root = Tk()

def func1():
    messagebox.showinfo('Pressed','you pressed 1')


def func2():
    messagebox.showinfo('Pressed','you pressed 2')


def hello():
    if int(e.get()) == 1:
        func1()
    elif int(e.get()) == 2:
        func2()
    else:
        messagebox.showinfo('Invalid','Enter valid text')


l = Label(root, text='Random Text')
l.pack()

e = Entry(root)
e.pack(padx=10, pady=20)

b = Button(root, text='Click me',command=hello)
b.pack(pady=10)

root.mainloop()
```

Hope it was of some help and you get an idea.

Cheers